# C# - variable reference does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I have this code in the main window class where I declare some values to put in a `ListForTesting` list and make the tests appear in a combobox. Later there is another combobox that depends on the first on which I present you the code down bellow:

It may be worth to mention that I am completely new to C#. Only coded in VBA. I'm a mechanical engineer, not software :)

**Main Window code**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid_projectConfig.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    grid_projectOverview.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    grid_test.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    grid_reports.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    //ListForTesting holds the hardcoded set of tests and manoeuvres
    List<HelpClass.TestID> ListForTesting = new List<HelpClass.TestID>();

    //TestObject holds the test name, ID and all the manoeuvres related to it
    HelpClass.TestID TestObject = new HelpClass.TestID();
    TestObject.testName = "Steady State";
    TestObject.ID = 0;
    //Manoeuvre holds the manoeuvre name and its ID
    TestObject.Manoeuvres = new List<HelpClass.ManoeuvresID>();
    HelpClass.ManoeuvresID Manoeuvre = new HelpClass.ManoeuvresID();
    Manoeuvre.manName = "30 kph";
    Manoeuvre.manID = 0;
    //add the Manoeuvre to the TestObject
    TestObject.Manoeuvres.Add(Manoeuvre);
    //create new Manoeuvre
    Manoeuvre = new HelpClass.ManoeuvresID();
    Manoeuvre.manName = "50 kph";
    Manoeuvre.manID = 1;
    TestObject.Manoeuvres.Add(Manoeuvre);
    //add the TestObject to the ListForTesting
    ListForTesting.Add(TestObject);


    //display the tests in a combobox
    combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Select(t => t.testName);
}
```

**Second combobox code**

```
public void combobox_testType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting[1].Manoeuvres.Select(t => t.manName);
}
```

this last line of code does not work because it tells me that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the *[scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)* of the variable `ListForTesting`: by declaring it inside your `MainWindow` constructor you limit its visibility to that method.
To allow to access `ListForTesting` from another method in your class (i.e.: `combobox_testType_SelectionChanged`) you have to declare it as a class-level variable like so:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<HelpClass.TestID> ListForTesting; // Variable declaration

    public MainWindow()
    {
        // code

        ListForTesting = new List<HelpClass.TestID>(); // Initialization

        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the variable `ListForTesting` is in the scope of the constructor. You need to move the variable out of there for it to be accessible elsewhere in the class.

```
List<HelpClass.TestID> ListForTesting;

public MainWindow()
{
...
   ListForTesting = new List<HelpClass.TestID>();
...
}
```